# Liquibase. Can updateSQL omit the query for the lock?

Tags: mysql, database, liquibase

This is the scenario: I have a existing production database without Liquibase, but for the develop enviroment I start to use Liquibase. Unlikely future changes in production must be done by a DBA executing SQL scripts. OK, I use liquibase:updateSQL for create them, the problem is that also generate the queries for taking the lock, for example:

```
--  *********************************************************************
--  Update Database Script
--  *********************************************************************
--  Change Log: src/main/resources/db/masterchangelog.xml
--  Ran at: 3/29/16 12:13 PM
--  Against: user@*.*.*.*@jdbc:mysql://*.*.*.*:3306/schema_name
--  Liquibase version: 3.4.1
--  *********************************************************************

--  Lock Database
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'fe80:0:0:0:5c63:d0ff:febe:1bc9%veth8848306 (fe80:0:0:0:5c63:d0ff:febe:1bc9%veth8848306)', LOCKGRANTED = '2016-03-29 12:13:24.142' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0;

--My DB Changes
UPDATE ...
INSERT ...
DELETE ...
etc

--  Release Database Lock
UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

As the table DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK doesn't exists in production, is there a way to omit this queries?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: This table is part of the LB internals  ,it being used to block parallel schema upgrade. ,If table do not exits ,liquibase will create it for you.

Comment: I know that, but in production we won't have Liquibase, we only will emulate the versioning with the scripts (updateSQL and rollbackSQL). Thanks anyway Mate.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no way to let liquibase not create the lock statement. The `updateSQL` will still assume that you use liquibase and that the lock table is there. `updateSQL` just defers the execution of all the SQL statements. Maybe you create an improvement ticket in liquibase jira to add an parameter or something to `updateSQL` so it will not write the statement to the final file.

Comment: The only way i see for you is to post procerss it via sed command like below

Comment: Yep, i had to add, manually:


sed -i  's/UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK/--UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK/g' output.sql
sed -i  's/INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK/--INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK/g' output.sql

Thanks anyway Mates